# Web scraping - how to read content of web site base on swf

Tags: c#, web-scraping

To read content of the html site I use WebClient:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] html      = client.DownloadData(url);
UTF8Encoding utf = new UTF8Encoding();
return utf.GetString(html);
```

The problem when site is like www.bet365.com. Odds are displayed in swf. How can I read odds ?
I cannot event display content of the site in Mozilla by Ctrl+U or Firebug. In IE (F12) Inspect works.

Thanks

Comment: You could do optical character recognition or OCR, that is method of scraping text from image, but you would have to take picture of webpage each time and then do OCR and after that use regex to extract data.But that seems like overkill and the data might get corrupted because OCR is far from perfect

Comment: oddsportal.com - thay do it in some way

Comment: This sounds like it might violate some laws...

Comment: Had a look with fiddler and results far from  encouraging, Wireshark may give a better insight but its a longshot. You could try to de-compile the Flash and see whats going on inside but that's seldom an easy process or if there is an android app that may yield an API way in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot scrape Flash content.

What you could do, however, is try to sniff the HTTP traffic initiated by the .swf, using a proxy tool, such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and pray that it's not encrypted.

By analyzing these HTTP requests you will be able to extract the ones that retrieve the data and automate them using `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.

Before automating data extraction, however, make sure it is allowed and you're not violating any of the website terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

they have a xml feed that they give out to affiliates, nobody is scraping their actual site